# Call overloaded constructor in list creation

Tags: c#

I have 2 constructor in my class like the following code:

```
class Foo 
{
    private int a {get; set;}
    public Foo(int val)
    {
        a = val;
    }
    public Foo() : this(0) {}
}
```

I use this class in a list, so when I call the construction of the list like :
`L = new List<Foo>()` it work, but if I want to use the overloaded constructor `L = new List<Foo>(10)` in example I can't, there anyone who can show me how to do that ?
Thank you.

Comment: `new List<Foo>(10)` instantiates an empty list with a capacity of 10. If you want to have a list filled with a single `Foo` called with `10` as the constructor argument, use `new List<Foo> { new Foo(10) }`. If you want to have a list that *only* instantiates `Foo`s with `10` for the value, you'll have to use some sort of factory method or wrapper class.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you construct a `List<Foo>`, you're not calling the `Foo` constructor at all - no `Foo` objects are created at all. This code:

```
L = new List<Foo>();
```

constructs an *empty* `List<Foo>`. If you want to add any elements to it, you could do so like this:

```
L.Add(new Foo());
L.Add(new Foo(10));
```

Or using a collection initializer:

```
L = new List<Foo>
{
    new Foo(),
    new Foo(10)
};
```

That allows you to construct the `Foo` objects (or use existing references) however you like.

Answer (score 0):

When you execute the following,

```
L = new List<Foo>();
```

a new instance of a List class is created, so the constructor that will get called here is the List class constructor from System.Collections.Generic

However the list object will hold a reference for 'Foo' class, but no object for 'Foo' will be created and hence the constructor won't be called.

However the constructor will get called when you execute the below lines

```
 L.Add(new Foo(100));
 L.Add(new Foo());
```

Hope it helps.